# Do I need to Get an Electrician In?

Tags: electrical, dishwasher

I got a new dishwasher coming in, Costco does not install or touch the old one. I disconnected the old dishwasher and removed it.

I was expecting to see an outlet to plug the new dishwasher in, but this was not the case.

I looked up a couple youtube videos and see some are connected by wires, but it seems by 3 wires.

The current one has a big metal disk with a black cable coming out that has a white connector at the end that connected to another white connector in the dishwasher.

I thought I might only need a plumber but now I am not sure and don't want to call one in and then they say they can't do it because of the electrical.

I was also evaluating if I can just hook it up myself.

It is a whirlpool - WDF341PAPM

[Owners Manual](https://www.whirlpool.com/content/dam/global/documents/202304/owners-manual-w11532445-revD.pdf)

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Whirlpool WDF341PAPM

Comment: Please put all information in your question, not down here. Also, asking whether you need an electrician is inappropriate. We have no idea what your ability and motivation may be. Please revise to ask _how to fix the problem_. You can then decide for yourself if you're up to the task.

Comment: As a suggestion. I do not recommend working with wiring in wet or potentially wet locations. Hire an electrician for your dishwasher and not worry about electrocuting your family.

Comment: Is the existing metal cable long enough to reach the new dishwasher's connection box directly?

Comment: Not sure yet, have not received the new dishwasher yet.  If I am just using the metal cable it won't be long enough. I think it will be a tad short as from the manual it seems like the box will be on the right side.

Answer (score 3):

That metal box is a standard steel junction box, which was not part of the previous dishwasher.  The cord from the junction box to the funny connector was definitely part of the old dishwasher and needs to go with it to its next owner.

NEC 110.3(B) requires you install the equipment according to instructions and labeling.  That implicitly requires that you read instructions and labeling.  If those provide for a hardwired solution, you can do the same as was done.  If they require cord-and-plug, then you will need to install a socket at an appropriate location…

…and – here's the trick – it must be GFCI protected.  Obviously that can be a bit of a messy problem, especially where there is not a convenient under-sink location for a new socket (since a GFCI must be readily accessible to test and reset), and if the panel is of an obsolete type where GFCI breakers of the correct type are not available. (That generally means Pushmatic, or the dangerous/faulty types of Zinsco or Federal Pacific.) Or it may be completely full of tandem breakers, requiring another circuit to be eliminated to make room for a GFCI.

*And now you know why Costco doesn't install. Too many variables/wildcards out there, and they are not going to be involved in jury-rigging some future liability*.

Answer (score 1):

The installation manual refers to the "power cord" but doesn't (unless I missed it) discuss plug/receptacle vs. hardwiring.

You *may* be able to chop off the end of the cord and strip the outer sheath and wire it up. But without knowing what you've really got there, that is a bit of a gamble. What is definitely safe and appropriate is a [wire whip](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-8-ft-12-2-Solid-CU-MC-Metal-Clad-Armorlite-Modular-Assembly-Quick-Cable-Whip-56482114/205846179#overlay):

[image: 8' 12 AWG wire whip]

Remove the old cord. Connect the wire whip into a knockout in your junction box and in the box attached to the dishwasher. Black to black. White to white. Green to ground screw in the box.

Comment: The existing cord doesn't have the required knockout fitting.  Reusing it could be an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: Electrical Connection 
– For Direct Wire, begin with step 7
– For Power Cord, wait until step 22
– For Factory Installed Power Cord, begin with Step 29

Comment: Sounds to me like the OP could nut a piece of NM to whatever is inside the round box, run it through the hole with the appropriate bushing, and hardwire to the D/W.  Also, if the D/W came with a plugged cord, a better solution might be to simply run NM to an outlet+box in the adjacent cabinet, drill a hole for the plug, and plug it in there.

Comment: @Huesmann Aha. I took another look and you are correct. Except that it looks like Step 7 is just to route the cable, and after that everything else is pretty much the same.

Comment: I added another picture it seems to have 3 wires though not sure what is going on with the gray one.

Comment: Oh I do see in the instructions the ground should look like that. Would the white plastic connector have to be cut off ? Though not sure if enough wire or that black piece will be hard to fit into the connector box

Comment: Remove the *entire* black cord, white connector, etc. - open the metal junction box and disconnect it. You aren't going to use it. Install a new cable from the junction box to the dishwasher.

Comment: Can't I keep the black cable and just cut after the big black part? Or why would I need a new cable from the junction box?

Comment: *Practically* speaking - yes, it would work. But you are butchering a piece of cord that was designed for a different dishwasher. We actually don't know if it was the right thing for this use in the first place - i.e., it may have been designed for **plug/cord** connection and already butchered on one end to hardwire. I don't recommend it. We're not talking big bucks here. And remember that this cord or cable will be sitting behind the dishwasher for 10 years or more - you want it to be rock solid.

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing that metal junction box was what was there before? If so “hardwiring” seems like a good option. That basically just means wire nutting all the different colored wires together (black to black, white to white, green/copper to green/copper) in the metal junction box. Looking at the existing cable you could probably just cut that off and feed it into the junction box?

All that being said it’d probably be best to have a professional look at this setup. Maybe there’s a simpler option you can go with. Any time there’s cutting going on it’s best to ask for experienced help! Looks like a pretty straightforward setup but it’s important that everything is done securely to if you go the hardwiring route.

Comment: Please tour the help. We expect an answer to add something new, not repeat a previous answer

Comment: See the [help] and take the [tour]. @RohitGupta: `[help]` and `[tour]`.